# Relation between irreducible polynomial and dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I found the following in my textbook:
Consider the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1)=:K$ ($\alpha_1$ is a root). Since $f=x^4-2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion or by reducing $f$ modulo $5$, we find that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1):\mathbb{Q}]=4$.

I don't understand how the dimension follows from the fact that $f$ is irreducible. Could somebody explain this to me? Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean that $\alpha_1$ is a root of $f$. If it's the case, then as $f$ is irreducible, it's the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$, and then you have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1) : \mathbb{Q}] = \deg(f)$.

Comment: What is your definition of dimension?

Comment: @ChocoSavour Yes that's right. Why is it true that if f is irreducible, it's the minimal polynomial?

Comment: @John Suppose that $f$ is not the minimal polynomial. Then it exists $g$ a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that : $g(\alpha_1)=0$, where $g$ is, this time, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$. But then, you can write : $f = gr + s$, where $\deg(s) < \deg(g)$ by Euclidean division. Then, as $f(\alpha_1) = g(\alpha_1) = 0$, you find that $s(\alpha_1)=0$. But as $\deg(s) < \deg(g)$ and $g$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_1$, you obtain a contradiction, unless $\deg(s) = 0$, i.e $s=0$ an $f=gr$. You can then use the irreducibility of $f$ to conclude.

Comment: @ChocoSavour So what do we need for f to be the minimal polynomial? When can we conclude that a polynomial is the minimal polynomial? Is this the case when the polynomial is irreducible?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a monic irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ in the ring $k[x].$ Given a root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$ in some field extension of $k,$ observe that the evaluation homomorphism $\operatorname{ev}_\alpha : k[x] \to k(\alpha)$ defined by $\operatorname{ev}_\alpha(p(x)) = p(\alpha)$ is surjective by definition of $k(\alpha).$ Considering that $\ker \operatorname{ev}_\alpha$ is an ideal of the principal ideal domain $k[x],$ it follows that $\ker \operatorname{ev}_\alpha = (p(x))$ for some monic polynomial $p(x).$ Consequently, we have that $p(x) \,|\, f(x).$ By hypothesis that $f(x)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial, we conclude that $p(x) = f(x)$ so that $\ker \operatorname{ev}_\alpha = (f(x)).$

By the First Isomorphism Theorem, we conclude that $k[x] / (f(x)) \cong k(\alpha).$ Considering that $$k[x] / (f(x)) = \{a_0 \overline 1 + a_1 \overline x + \cdots + a_{n - 1} \overline x^{n - 1} \,|\, a_i \in k \}$$ is a $k$-vector space, it follows that its dimension over $k$ is $n,$ hence we have that $[k(\alpha) : k] = n.$

Answer (score 0):

Since the polynomial is of degree 4, a basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3$ (since $\alpha^4=2\in \mathbb{Q}$).

Answer (score 0):

Since , the minimal polynomial is of degree 4, hence the elements of the field can be expressed as linear combination of four basis elements of 1,a,a²,a³ over $\mathbb{Q}$ ,where a is the root(a⁴=2). You can think also it as vector space with basis {1,a,a²,a³} over $\mathbb{Q}$.(since, any field is a vector space over any of it's subfield).